# Solving for the positive constants $a$ and $b$ in $a\left[0.9^xK_0\right]^{-b}-aK_0^{-b} = \theta\left[\frac{1-p^x}{1-p}\right].$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm looking at the following question.

Suppose I have some output from a process. As an example, we pretend this output is the cost of setting up a production machine, everytime I want to produce a batch of some product. Let's call this the setup cost and denote this as $K$.

Now, to improve and thus lower $K$, it costs money. And let's denote the cost to get to a certain setup cost as $a_K(K)$.

We assume now, that this cost is a power function like the following:

$$a_K(K) = aK^{-b}-d, $$

for $0 < K \le K_0$ and with positive constants $a, b, d$ and $K_0$.
You can view $K_0$ as the original setup cost.

Also, not that:

$$a_K(K_0) = aK_0^{-b}-d = 0$$

and thus $d = aK_0^{-b}$.

We can interpret the function $a_K(K)$ as follows: the cost of reducing the setup cost with a fixed percentage (let's say $10$%), grows with a certain fixed percentage (let's say $5$%) everytime we reduce the cost with that $10$%.

For example, if the starting setup cost $K_0$ is $100$, it may costs $200$€ to reduce the setup cost to $90$, $210$€ (five percent more than $200$€) to reduce it to $81$, $220.5$€ to reduce it to $72.9$, and so on.

Let's denote the fixed percentage, which is $5$ in our example, as $\gamma$ and that $200$ as $\theta$.
The goal now is to find the constants $a$ and $b$ that satisfy this relationship.

According to my textbook, the solutions for finding $a$ and $b$ are:

$$b = \frac{-\ln(p)}{\ln(0.9)}$$,

where $p=1+\gamma$ and we use $0.9$ because of the $10$% in the example.

$$a = \frac{K^b\theta}{0.9^{-b}-1}.$$

**How I started:**

I looked at it by knowing that $K$ can be expressed as $K = 0.9^xK_0$, for every $x-$times we reduce the setup cost with $10$%.

Now, the cost $a_K(K)$ can be calculated recursively in terms of this $x-$times:

$$f(0) = 0$$

$$f(x+1) = p^x\theta+f(x)$$,

which is a geometric series and thus can be calculated as $\theta\left[\frac{1-p^x}{1-p}\right]$.

So, I was thinking that I should solve for $a$ and $b$ by starting from the following equation:

$$a\left[0.9^xK_0\right]^{-b}-aK_0^{-b} = \theta\left[\frac{1-p^x}{1-p}\right].$$

But I don't see how we can get to the expressions for $a$ and $b$ from this.

Am I missing something?

Any help and/or hints are appreciated.